# Can This Solution to the Google Foobar "Re-ID" be more efficient?

Tags: python

I'm looking for guidance on a better way to solve Google's Re-ID problem. Instead of typing out the "Re-ID" description here, I will simply list the pertinent parts:

1. There are 10,000 "Minions" each of which are assigned an integer randomly between 0 and 10000 inclusive.
2. The Minion will look up his integer as an index in a string of concatenated prime numbers - i.e. `2357111317192329...`
3. His new "ID" is generated by finding the index value in the string according to the Minion's integer assignment and concatenating the next 4 numbers with it - i.e. if the Minion's integer assignment is `3` his new ID would be `71113` (`7` is the value at index 3 of the string, then we add the next 4 digits/characters)

To solve this I:

1. Utilized (thanks again, SO) a function to identify if a number is prime or not: `is_prime()`
2. Generated a string of all prime numbers concatenated together which facilitates a Minion with assignment "10000" plus the next 4 characters.
3. Created a function to generate the new ID based on the Minion's assignment and the string of concatenated values: `answer()`

```
import math
def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2: 
        return False
    return all(n % i for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))

primes = ''

for i in range(2,21000,1):
    if len(primes) < 10005:
        if is_prime(i):
            primes = primes + str(i)
    else:
        break

def answer(n):
    re_id = primes[n:n+5:1]
    return(re_id)
```

Areas of possible improvement

1. The `21000` in my for loop is completely arbitrary. By trial and error I found 21,000 facilitates a Minion integer assignment of 10000 plus the 5 additional digits/characters.
2. Is it necessary to create this long string of concatenated prime numbers before hand? Could it not be done dynamically based on the Minion ID?

Thanks for your insights. Happy Friday.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to "zoom in" without visiting the earlier primes; if there was, that would have pretty profound consequences for number theory.

You don't need the magic number 20500 (just stop once you've enough digits) or to remember primes (just track how many digits you've seen and keep ones starting from the id index.).

Keeping the magic number and storage, it might be more efficient to pre-generate a set of primes (e.g. Sieve of Eratosthenes) rather than running individual primality tests.

Finally, no one should use this scheme to assign ids - can you tell why?

Answer (score 2):

I have used this code to complete the challenge..

```
def solution(b):
bag = "2"
for num in range(0,20500):
    if num > 1:
        for j in range(2,num):
            if (num % j) == 0:
                break
            elif len(bag) >= 10006:
                break
            elif j==num-1:
                bag += str(num)
                break
            else:
                continue

return bag[b:b+5]
```